# NETBeans GlassFish Server The module has not been deployed

Tags: netbeans, module, glassfish

```
Starting GlassFish Server 4.1.1
GlassFish Server 4.1.1 is running.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Mesci\Desktop\Java\NetBeansProjeleri\WebApplication1\build\web
GlassFish Server 4.1.1, deploy, Connection refused: connect, false
C:\Users\Mesci\Desktop\Java\NetBeansProjeleri\WebApplication1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)
```

I've got error like this. And there is 1045. line :

> < nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false"
>   forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>

I've just setup NetBeans and when I try my first index.html, I've got anerror.

Comment: May be proxy server setting issue.In Netbeans goto **Tools** - **Options**  and select **No Proxy** and OK.